# Check whether method is a class method and call attribute

Tags: python, class, object, decorator, python-decorators

I built a little decorator for logging purposes.

```
def func_detail(func):
    def func_wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        log(func.__name__+' ARGS: {}'.format(str(args)))
        return func(*args,**kwargs)
    return func_wrapper
```

This works for both object methods and normal methods. I want to use it in multithreading. I have a class which contains `pid` as an object attribute. Is it possible to change the decorator to `log` `pid` if it detects that the method belongs to some class and this class contains attribute `pid`?

I've tried:

```
def func_detail(func):
    def func_wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        log('PID: '+self.pid if self.pid is not None else ' '+func.__name__+' ARGS: {}'.format(str(args)))
        return func(*args,**kwargs)
    return func_wrapper
```

But this not works at all. Could you help me?

**ABSTRACT**:

I want to be able to call attribute `pid` from the `class` where the method (`func`) belongs without passing `self` as an argument to the wrapper because in that case it would not works for methods which aren't inside a classes.

Comment: You said it doesn't work. Do you mean you get an attribute error? If not please explain.

Comment: @kobejohn For example just print - print self.pid
NameError: global name 'self' is not defined It's because decorator doesn't know that it will be used on object method. It can be use outside a function either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `self` argument to methods is not magically made available to your `func_wrapper` function in your decorator. Rather, it will be the first of the position arguments you're capturing with `*args`. If you want to make use of it, you'll need to examine `args[0]` and see if it has a `pid` attribute.

Try this, which checks first that a first argument exists, then that if it has a `pid` attribute:

```
log('{}FUNC: {} ARGS: {}'.format('PID: {} '.format(args[0].pid)
                                 if args and hasattr(args[0], "pid") else '',
                                 func.__name__, args))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling a method, the object itself will be the first parameter, the `self` in the method implementation.

If your decorator was only applied to methods (defined as `def methodName(self, ...):`) you could capture the first parameter in self.

Then you could try to print self.pid and catch the exception if there isn't any such attribute.

Since there is little distinction between free functions and method, I think that you should define two decorators one for free function, and  another for method, or define a decorator taking a parameter saying wether it is a method or not.

Another solution is to check if the args isn't empty and print args[0].pid if it exists.